# Get wkhtmltopdf to recognize user font folder

Tags: fonts, installation, wkhtmltopdf

I think I have my problem pinpointed here...I've installed some non-standard fonts into my ~/.fonts directory and run 'mkfontdir' and 'mkfontscale'.  The fonts show up when I list them with 'fc-list'.  The problem remains that wkhtmltopdf doesn't recognize them.  Other system fonts like 'Courier 10 Pitch' are recognized...just not what's in my user directory.  So is there a way to get wkhtmltopdf (or for that matter, webkit) to recognize the fonts in my folder?  Is there something I have to do over ssh or is there an option I can set in ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Does the problem still exist? I just tried with a virtual Ubuntu server and got fonts working without any problems even though the version I got from the repositories is 0.9.9 which is pretty old. My process:

1. Installed xserver, fluxbox, mupdf (viewer), chromium and wkhtmltopdf
2. Got an awesome font (PonyRides)
3. Ran mkfontdir, mkfontscale and fc-list (font showed up on list)
4. Made a test.html with a single paragraph that used the custom font
5. `wkhtmltopd test.html test.pdf`

I checked the pdf locally and then on another computer and the custom font even worked there even though I didn't have the font installed. http://temp-share.com/show/dPf3m39HW <- generated PDF (I hope the link is not too temporary).

Comment: Would this work if the fonts are stored in, for eg, css/fonts? I can't get wkhtmltopdf to work with my fonts either - I'm on a shared hosting plan. (btw, awesome font!:) )